# Testing embedded spaces in c

Tags: c

I want to create a function in C programming, which will test for the embedded spaces in C.

if it found embedded spaces in a string it will return 1 else 0

examples:

```
'sjdfnsdj' >>>>> return 0
'sdsd sdsdf' >>>>> return 1
'    ssadsa' >>> return 0
'dfjksdnf sdfsdfdf' >>>> return 1
' sadf asdad' >>>> return 1
```

Embedded spaces means spaces between two strings or after the string but NOT before a string

Comment: So, what does your function code look like currently?

Comment: @ruslik, what is the basis for the `homework` retag?

Comment: @jball "need a function in C programming". Also original tags "c embedded space". And age :) : 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/) to scan the string for a space character after you you skipped leading spaces.

Assuming char buf[] holds the string to test

```
int i=0;
while ( buf[i] == ' ' && buf[i] != '\0' )
  i++;

return strchr( &buf[i], ' ' ) != NULL;
```

---

EDIT: The post has been retagged with homework.

Instead of using strchr you can also do another loop like the one to skip the leading spaces. To find out whether there are further spaces after the first non space char.

Comment: Single strchr has an issue with trailing space that is "   abcd   " will pass this test.

Answer (score 1):

This might help, basically you need a simple state machine.

```
int CheckEmbeddedStr(char *str)
{
    //0 - No Start str
    //1 - Start str seen
    //2 - embedded space seen
    //3 - trailing str seen
    int state=0; 
    int count=0;
    while(str && str[count])
    {
        if(state == 0 && isalpha(str[count]))
            state++;
        if(state == 1 && str[count] = ' ')
            state++;
        if(state == 2 && isalpha(str[count]))
        {
            state++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(state==3)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```